# como puedo hacer para que no se corte abruptamente la ultima palabra en mi la particion del string que introduje en la funcion

Tags: python, string, bucle-for

he creado una función que particiona un strig en 280 caracteres, pero quiero que cuando la ultima palabra sobrepase el limite de caracteres, se elimine esta ultima palabra y quedé el resto de caracteres antes de esta. No sé que modificación pueda hacerle a mi codigo para lograr este objetivo

```
 n_de_twit =0 #inicializacion de la variable n_de_twit (me da el numero total de twits que va 
 #a alcanzar a formar el usuario con el texto ingresado )

 texto = str(input("introduzca el texto: ")) #texto que ingresa el usuario para descomponer en 
 #una cantidad de twits 

 n = len(texto) #cantidad de caracteres presente en el texto 
 twit = [] #aqui se guarda cada twit, es decir cada cadena de caracteres con 280 caracteres
 def twit_funcion(texto,n,twit):
 #indicamos que inicia desde 0 hasta la longitud del texto con un salto de 280 caracteres 
 for i in range(0,len(texto), 280): #inicio, funal, paso
     twit.append(texto[i:i+280])  #cogemos desde i hasta i+280 y agregamos
     n_de_twit= len(twit)

 for k in range(len(twit)): #recorre la lista twit 
     print(twit[k]) #se imprimen los componentes de la lista twit 
     print(len(twit[k]),"/280") #me da el numero de caracteres que ocupa cada twit 
     n_twit_actual = k+1 #enumera cada uno de los twits 
     print("este es el twit actual",n_twit_actual,"/",n_de_twit) # imprimen la enumeracion de 
 los twit sobre la cantidad de twits 
 return(twit[k],n_de_twit,n_twit_actual) 
 l = twit_funcion(texto, n, twit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es que no sé si se puede responderte, porque no has hecho una pregunta sobre python en sí, sino de lógica de programación, pero lo haría de otra forma, ya que más que caracteres querés mantener palabras, entonces sería muy díficil determinar que caracteres eliminar o dejar para que tengan sentido semántico,así que no voy a replicar tu método sino que implemento otro:

```
cadena="""he creado una función que particiona un strig en 280 caracteres, pero quiero que cuando la ultima palabra sobrepase el limite de caracteres,
se elimine esta ultima palabra y quedé el resto de caracteres antes de esta. 
No sé que modificación pueda hacerle a mi codigo para lograr este objetivo"""
```

por una cuestión de pocas ganas de buscar, usaré tu texto

```
def twit_funcion(texto):
    lista=texto.split()
    twit=[]
    suma=0
```

creo la función pero solo le paso como argumento el texto, creo una lista de palabras en base al texto, una lista vacía y una variable de suma

```
 for x in lista:
        suma+=(len(x))+1
        if suma <= 280:
            twit.append(x)
    return " ".join(twit)
```

ahora simplemente recorro la lista de texto le sumo el largo de cada palabra  más 1 (porque  después necesito espacios)a la variable suma
por último verifico que si la suma es menor o igual a 280 y la agrego a la lista twit. Finalmente convierto esa lista en una cadena

```
print(twit_funcion(cadena))
```

resultado:

```
"""he creado una función que particiona un strig en 280 caracteres, pero quiero que cuando la ultima palabra sobrepase el limite de caracteres,
se elimine esta ultima palabra y quedé el resto de caracteres antes de esta. No sé que modificación pueda hacerle a mi codigo para lograr"""
```

y si le sacas el largo será de 278 carcateres.
espero que si no te sirve, te oriente.

Comment: *"...porque no has hecho una pregunta sobre python en sí..."* el código de la pregunta no es python?

Comment: el código si, pero no manifiesta que no entienda sobre el lenguaje, quiere implementar más código, no que le expliquen que hace mal.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución con expresiones regulares.

La expresión regular `.{1,280}\s` reconoce una cadena de entre 1 a 280 caracteres cualquiera, después de lo cual tiene que venir un espacio en blanco.

Al poner la expresión entre paréntesis `(.{1,280}\s)`, indico que la quiero *capturar*, es decir, que me devuelva una lista con las partes que cumplen la condición.

Con `compile` creo un objeto que reconoce este patrón.

```
patron = re.compile("(.{1,280})\s",re.DOTALL)
```

El parámetro `re.DOTALL` indica aceptar el `\n` como un caracter más. Normalmente el patrón punto (`.`) reconoce todos los caracteres excepto el  `\n`.

Con `findall` divido el texto en partes:

```
patron.findall(cadena)
```

obteniendo como resultado una lista de cadenas.

Con esto puedo crear una función que reciba la cadena y el largo que se desea cortar. Sólo me queda reemplazar `{1,280}` por una expresión más general, reemplazando `280` por un parámetro:

```
def partir(cadena, n):
    patron = re.compile("(.{1," + str(n) +"})\s", re.DOTALL)
    return patron.findall(cadena)
```

**Demo**

```
import re

cadena="""he creado una función que particiona un strig en 280 caracteres, pero quiero que cuando la ultima palabra sobrepase el limite de caracteres,
se elimine esta ultima palabra y quedé el resto de caracteres antes de esta. 
No sé que modificación pueda hacerle a mi codigo para lograr este objetivo"""

def partir(cadena, n):
    patron = re.compile("(.{1," + str(n) +"})\s", re.DOTALL)
    return patron.findall(cadena)

for linea in partir(cadena, 280):
    print(len(linea), linea)
```

produce:

```
279 he creado una función que particiona un strig en 280 caracteres, pero quiero que cuando la ultima palabra sobrepase el limite de caracteres,
se elimine esta ultima palabra y quedé el resto de caracteres antes de esta. 
No sé que modificación pueda hacerle a mi codigo para lograr
4 este

Process finished with exit code 0
```